# Ramadan and fasting swallowing water that enters by accident

Tags: fiqh, sharia, sin, sawm, ramadan

I was doing wudu in the masjid. I didn’t dry my face with a towel. After a few minutes a drop of water from my face slips into my mouth. I swallow it because the jamat is starting. Is my fast valid? Do I have to fast for 60 days? Please answer

Comment: There are numerous questions like yours that have been answered. Please Google your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No if it was an accident then your fast is valid. If you swallow the drop of water on purpose your fast was broken